# correct method "get next value"

Tags: java

This code isn't working.  Can you help me fix it?

```
// need to get next parameter
static double getParametr()
{
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    param = scanner.nextDouble();
    return param;
}
// ...
// ...
if (i==1)
{
    System.out.println("vvedite storoni pryamougolnika:  ");
    Shape parA = new Rectangle();
    parA.a = Shape.getParametr(); --- this is ok
    double aa = parA.a;
    Shape parB = new Rectangle();
    parB.b = Shape.getParametr();  ------ this is no work!!! 
    double bb = parB.b;
    Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(aa, bb);
    arrayFigur[i] = rec.area();
}
```

Comment: Please highlight code and press code button in editor

Comment: Does this code throw any exception or something? It looks fine.

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't work? Are you entering another double once you reach that point in your code?

Comment: Also, can you tell us what error messages you get, etc.?  What are you sending in System.in?  (command line?)

Comment: Is this a compile-time error or a runtime error? Could you provide the error message?

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to guess that parB.b is non-existant, or maybe it isn't even a double. You really need to give us more information though.

Note: Creating a new Scanner object everytime you invoke getParametr() is inefficient.

Comment: my java and english are not perfect)) i have not error messages or exeptions. program is "hangs" or "hold":)

Comment: i think a have problem in getParametr() but i cant rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that you create a new Scanner for every parameter you want to parse in. Perhaps the first Scanner reads more characters from the input than you need for your first parameter. Then a new Scanner is created for the next parameter, but there the stream isn't positioned exactly after the first parameter ends.

You should create only one Scanner and use this instance for all parsing.